# Date Time Conversion not working for a custom string of datetime

Tags: c#

I have this string **01-Oct-19-03_13_AM** when i try to `DateTime.Parse` method it says String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Any Solution will be helpful.

Comment: [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Use `ParseExact` if you know that the format will **always** be the same, or  `TryParseExact` if you're not sure (like, when getting the string from a human, for instance)

Comment: I tried this but still error is same Please review
 'string dt = "01-Oct-19-03_13_AM";
item.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd-mm-yy hh:mm tt", rovider).ToString();'

Comment: Please provide clarification as an edit to your question instead of as a comment.

Comment: You are instructing `ParseExact` that your date is in format `dd-mm-yy hh:mm tt`. There are two problems here: 1) `mm` means minutes, `MM` means months. 2) There are no spaces in your date, you have underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ParseExact`, or `TryParseExact` with a specified custom format to achieve this.

The custom date format specifies each part of the date in the format you have it.  In your case, it should be:

```
01-Oct-19-03_13_AM
dd-MMM-yy-hh_mm_tt
```

Here's an example with `TryParseExact` (my preference):

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("01-Oct-19-03_13_AM", "dd-MMM-yy-hh_mm_tt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime myDate))
    Console.WriteLine(myDate);
```

This outputs:

```
01/10/2019 03:13:00
```

For your reference, custom date formats are described in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Awsome Excellent